# How do I wrap a span around a section of text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have markup like this:

```
<p>one two three four</p>
```

And I want to use javascript to convert it to this:

```
<p>one <span>two three<span> four</p>
```

I have the offset and length of the section I want to wrap in a span, in this case `offset = 4` and `length = 9`. If using jQuery can make it easier, that is preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this not a little duplicate of the question **[Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441)** ?

Something like the [JQuery search highlight plugin](http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight/demo_en.html) could be helpful

Or, as [pointed out in the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441#120289), write your own jquery function:
Something like (untested code, feel free to edit):

```
jQuery.fn.addSpan = function (elName, str, offset, length)
{
    if(this.innerHTML = str)
    {
        return this.each(function ()
        {
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substring(0,offset) + "<span>" + this.innerHTML.substring(offset, offset+length) + "</span>" + this.innerHTML.substring(offset+length));
        });
    }
};
```

And you would use it like so:

```
$("p").addSpan("one two three four", 4, 9);
```