# change substring color inside hyperlink

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple links on a page that looks like this

```
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">20 | 11-APRIL-2012 | 349 | MDP | MR ABC, | Street 4 ,abc@example.com,</a>
```

I want to change the color of MR ABC to red... any jquery selector

Comment: Is there possibility to change markup?

Comment: What's the criteria for the element to change to red? Always the fifth element? Always starting 'MR'? We need to know, else we can't tell you how to get JS to traverse your anchor for the relevant substring.

Comment: @Jimmy Breck-McKye always the fifth element

Comment: I would manage that in markup, then, as it sounds like the fifth element is a value in a column with semantic value. Semantics should be managed in markup - never presentational CSS or Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

To highlight the text you can use inner `span`:

```
​$("a.ui-corner-all").html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/(MR ABC)/, "<span style='color: #ff0000'>$1</span>");
})​​​;​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qY4M7/

Comment: MR ABC will not be the same for all links

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('a.ui-corner-all').html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(new RegExp('(MR ABC)', "g"), "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
});
```

and on your css:

```
span.highlight {
    color: #00FF0F
}
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mx5T6/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Thought about wrapping the desired text in a `span` tag an and adding a css rule for it?

`a.ui-corner-all span {color: red;}`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this **[Wrap a span around a word in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300129/how-do-i-wrap-a-span-around-a-section-of-text-in-javascript)** ?

Basically you can use a the jQuery search highlight plugin or just write your own little function to find a substring and wrap it in a `span` and then apply css styles to it.