# How to search/replace text with an "a href" wrapper in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, text, replace

I've converted html to a string, I'm able to use replace in that string to wrap the text with a link, and I can put that html back into the ID it came from.

My problem is that my replace method is going *inside* existing links on the page. This could create nested links, which is a problem. Does anyone out there know how to prevent the replace method from matching text that is within a link already?

I have right now:

```
keyword = "matching phrase";
keywordLink = "<a href='http://myurl.com'/>" + keyword + "</a>";
sasser = sasser.replace(keyword, keywordLink);
sasDom.innerHTML = sasser;
```

I'm looking for, in pseudo code:

```
... (keyword [if the next " < " sign is not followed by "/a>", regardless of how far away it is], keywordLink);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this kind of thing with regex at all. Work on the document objects which are already nicely parsed into a structure for you.

Here's a keyword linker adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word).

```
// Find text in descendents of an element, in reverse document order
// pattern must be a regexp with global flag
//
function findTextExceptInLinks(element, pattern, callback) {
    for (var childi= element.childNodes.length; childi-->0;) {
        var child= element.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType===1) {
            if (child.tagName.toLowerCase()!=='a')
                findTextExceptInLinks(child, pattern, callback);
        } else if (child.nodeType===3) {
            var matches= [];
            var match;
            while (match= pattern.exec(child.data))
                matches.push(match);
            for (var i= matches.length; i-->0;)
                callback.call(window, child, matches[i]);
        }
    }
}

findTextExceptInLinks(document.body, /\bmatching phrase\b/g, function(node, match) {
    node.splitText(match.index+match[0].length);
    var a= document.createElement('a');
    a.href= 'http://www.example.com/myurl';
    a.appendChild(node.splitText(match.index));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(a, node.nextSibling);
});
```

eta re comments: Here's a version of the same thing using plain text matching rather than regex:

```
function findPlainTextExceptInLinks(element, substring, callback) {
    for (var childi= element.childNodes.length; childi-->0;) {
        var child= element.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType===1) {
            if (child.tagName.toLowerCase()!=='a')
                findPlainTextExceptInLinks(child, substring, callback);
        } else if (child.nodeType===3) {
            var index= child.data.length;
            while (true) {
                index= child.data.lastIndexOf(substring, index);
                if (index===-1)
                    break;
                callback.call(window, child, index)
            }
        }
    }
}

var substring= 'matching phrase';
findPlainTextExceptInLinks(document.body, substring, function(node, index) {
    node.splitText(index+substring.length);
    var a= document.createElement('a');
    a.href= 'http://www.example.com/myurl';
    a.appendChild(node.splitText(index));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(a, node.nextSibling);
});
```

Comment: Bobince - thank you so much! This solution is fantastic, and I greatly appreciate your taking the time to post it.

I'm having one relatively simple problem now... I can't seem to use a variable as the matching phrase. Here's what I'm trying:

    findTextExceptInLinks(document.body, "/\b" + variable + "\b/g", function(node, match) {

Comment: findTextExceptInLinks(document.body, "/\b" + variable + "\b/g", function(node, match) {

Comment: @google: try passing `new RegExp('\\b' + variable + '\\b', 'g')`

Comment: Yep, the `RegExp` constructor as posted by Crescent will work, but watch out: if your variable contains characters that are special to regex like `.` or `*` (most punctuation really), this won't match the literal versions of the string. If you want to match literal strings rather than words-at-boundaries, it'd be better to dump the regular expression matching and replace with `string.indexOf`.

Comment: To be clear, you're suggesting I change:

 ... 

while (match= pattern.exec(child.data))

 ... 

to

 ... 

while (match= string.indexOf(child.data))

Comment: ah, no, there'd be a few more changes as the string matching interface is a bit different... actually, a bit easier. Added plain-text version to answer.

Comment: You're a champ bobince. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com), you can employ its [`wrap()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) function to wrap text or html elements in the specified tags.

Comment: Does that work for wrapping only part of the text inside some tags, too?

Comment: Thinking about it, it will probably not keep you from having nested link tags, or will it?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in three steps:

1) replace `<a [^>]+>matching phrase</a>` with `$1some_other_phrase</a>`

2) replace `matching phrase` with `<a...>keyword</a>`

3) replace `some_other_phrase` with `matching phrase`