# Highlight text, except html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the code below to highlight some keywords in a text:

```
$message = str_ireplace($words,'<span class="hightlighted_text">'.$words.'</span>',$message);
```

The text may contain some html tags, for example `<img>`, `<strong>`, etc..

How can I highlight "normal" text, except the text between the html tags? Because when users search for "img" the `<img>` text will be highlighted and the image doesn't work anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590862/match-multiple-terms-within-body-tags/2590969#2590969 (just an hour ago!)

Answer (score 4):

Use a DOM parser of some sort. This is not something you want to do with regex.

Answer (score 2):

From http://forum.phpfrance.com/vos-contributions/remplacement-selectif-hors-dans-balises-html-t199.html

```
function mon_rplc_callback($capture){
  global $arg;
  return ($arg['flag'] == 1)
  ? $arg['fct']($arg['from'], $arg['to'], $capture[1]).$capture[2]
  : $capture[1].$arg['fct']($arg['from'], $arg['to'], $capture[2]);
}

function split_tag($from, $to, $txt, $fct, $flag = 1){
  global $arg;
  $arg = compact('from', 'to', 'fct', 'flag');
  return preg_replace_callback('#((?:(?!<[/a-z]).)*)([^>]*>|$)#si', "mon_rplc_callback", $txt);
}
```

When $flag == 1, the replacement function is applied outside HTML.
When $flag == -1, the replacement function is applied inside HTML.

Applied to your example, it would give something like this:

```
echo split_tag($words, '<span class="hightlighted_text">'.$words.'</span>', $message, 'str_ireplace', 1);
```

Enjoy! ;)

Comment: Thanks, but this is without an html parser. The above posters said that a html parser would be better in this case (??)

Comment: And I tell you regular expressions can do a very good job. Plus you won't need to have a valid html code: it will just work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only problem is when de keywords (that has to be highlighted) contains all alpha numeric characters I get a memory leak error.

Comment: Hum. That looks strange. Can you provide the code you used?

Btw I just read the argument about why regex can't parse HTML. I quite agree with the whole thing, but the problem is MUCH simpler here: we just need to know whether we are inside some HTML tag or not. We don't have to parse an HTML structure and interpreting a tree and mismatching tags or some other errors. We just know that a HTML tag is something between < and >. I believe the regex is very adapted here.

Answer (score 0):

Better code based on reply from @Savageman

```
$str = '<a href="ba">ba</a>';
$highlightWhat = "ba";
$str = preg_replace_callback('#((?:(?!<[/a-z]).)*)([^>]*>|$)#si', function($m) use ($highlightWhat) {
            return preg_replace('~('.$highlightWhat.')~i', '<span style="background:#fff330">$1</span>', $m[1]) . $m[2];
        },
        $str);
```