# PHP: Replace Double Quotes in String But Not Those Within HTML Tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Looking for the best solution on how to replace regular quotes within a block of text with curly quotes, but not to change quotes found within html tag markers <....> I have attempted using preg-replace, such as:

```
$pattern = '/(?<!=)"\b/';
$lyrics = preg_replace($pattern, "\u201c", $lyrics);
$pattern = '/\b"(?!>)/';
$lyrics = preg_replace($pattern, "\u201d", $lyrics);
$pattern = '/\."/'; // find regular quotes after a period
$lyrics = preg_replace($pattern, ".\u201d", $lyrics);
$pattern = '/\!"/'; // find regular quotes after an exclamation
$lyrics = preg_replace($pattern, "!\u201d", $lyrics);
$pattern = '/"\s/'; // find regular quotes before a space
$lyrics = preg_replace($pattern, "\u201d ", $lyrics);
```

For example, if I have the following:

```
<a href="http://somelink.com">"This is a quotation."
```

I want it to end up as:

```
<a href="http://somelink.com">“This is a quotation.”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HTML parser which allows you to access text nodes easily. A regular expression is [not really suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If it's properly formed, you could even use an xml parser. But you'd need all tags opened and closed first (or some in this way: `< /br>` ). Then, you can [parse the xhtml with php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) as regular xml.

EDITED: Possible duplicate of [Highlight text, except html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591046/highlight-text-except-html-tags)