# jquery: find a string and wrap it in an <a> tag?

Tags: jquery

i've got this:

```
<div class="" id="fancy_hover">
    <a href="home.html" id="start_writer"></a>  
    <div>
        <p class="hidden" style="display: block;">click here to see this event with all the bells and whistles</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to do an equivalent of `.find()` but for the string `"click here"` instead of a node, i then need to wrap it in an `<a>` tag.

Whats the best approach with jquery?

Comment: Do you need to wrap the whole text node in an `<a>` tag or just the words "click here"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `:contains` filter selector:

```
$('p.hidden:contains("click here")')
```

**To wrap it in link:**

```
$('p.hidden:contains("click here")').html()
.replace('click here', '<a href="url">click here</a>');
```

**To wrap whole text in link:**

```
$('p.hidden:contains("click here")')
.html('<a href="url">' + $('p.hidden:contains("click here")').text() + '<a>');
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Helpful answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Don't use HTML string hacking. Imagine what would happen if you tried to replace over `<span title="blah click here blah">...</span>` with an `<a>` tag... massively broken markup. And that's only the beginning of the problems.

Instead, iterate over the text nodes in the part of the document you want to examine, looking for text matches and inserting a new link using DOM-style methods.

jQuery doesn't really help you much here as it has no functionality for handling text nodes. Instead, use something like the `findText()` function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word/1501213#1501213) and use `splitText` to split up the text node:

```
findText($('#fancy_hover')[0], /\bClick here\b/gi, function(node, match) {
    node.splitText(match.index+match[0].length);
    var link= document.createElement('a');
    link.href= 'http://www.example.com/';
    link.appendChild(node.splitText(match.index));
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(link, node.nextSibling);
});
```