# Text Search - Highlighting the Search phrase

Tags: php, javascript, html

What will be the best way to highligh the Searched pharase within a HTML Document.

I have Complete HTML Document as a Large String in a Variable.
And I want to Highlight the searched term excluding text with Tags.

For example if the user searches for "img" the img tag should be ignored but
phrase "img" within the text should be highlighted.

Comment: Do you mean in the user browser ? If so, it's a pure javascript question that should be retagged

Comment: As far as i understand, this is about javascript, not java nor programming-languages -> retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't use regex.*

Because regex cannot parse HTML (or even come close), any attempt to mess around with matching words in an HTML string risks breaking words that appear in markup. A badly-implemented HTML regex hack can even leave you with HTML-injection vulnerabilities which an attacker may be able to leverage to do cross-site-scripting.

Instead you should parse the HTML and do the searches on the text content only.

If you can accept a solution that adds the highlighting from JavaScript on the client side, this is really easy because the browser will already have parsed the HTML into a bunch of DOM objects you can manipulate. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word) for a client-side example.

If you have to do it with PHP that's a bit more tricky. The simple solution would be to use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` and then translate the `findText` function from the above example into PHP. At least the DOM methods used are standardised so they work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This was tagged as Java before, so this answer might not be applicable.

This is quick and dirty but it might work for you, or at least be a starting point

```
private String highlight(String search,String html) {
    return html.replaceAll("(>[^<]*)("+search+")([^>]*<)","$1<em>$2</em>$3");
}
```

This requires testing, and I make no guarantees that its correct but the simplest way to explain how is that you ensure that your term exists between two tags and is thus is not itself a tag or part of a tag parameter.

Comment: JavaSCRIPT, not Java ;) Edit: Ah, I see you have been confused by the tag 'java'.

Comment: Yup, I kept the answer since the regex is at least relevant :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var highlight = function(what){
   var html  = document.body.innerHTML,

       word  = "(" + what + ")",
       match = new RegExp(word, "gi");

   html = html.replace(match, "<span style='background-color: red'>$1</span>");

   document.body.innerHTML = html;
};

highlight('ll');
```

This would highlight any occurence of 'll'.

Be carefull by calling `highlight()` with `<` or `>` or any `tag name`, it would also replace those, screwing up your markup. You might workaround that by reading `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`, but that way you'll lose the markup information.

Best way probably is to implement a parser routine yourself.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/DRtVn/

Answer (score 0):

there is a free javascript library that might help you out -> http://scott.yang.id.au/code/se-hilite/

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some server side language to render the search results on the webpage.

So the best way I can think of is to highlight the word while rendering it using the server side language itself,which may be php,java or any other language.

This way you would have only the result strings without html and without parsing overhead.