# How to detect where the word is wrapped

Tags: javascript, line, word-wrap, detect

I would like to add 'span' tag on the beginning and '/span' on the end of each line of text as it is presented in the website and change it dynamically when a div containing such text is resized. The problem is that I don't know how to detect where the text is being wrapped - if I had such information it would be easy. So my question is: is there a way to determine where the text is wrapped using javascript?
I have found a javascript library which hyphenates the text in the site but I'm not sure how does it detect line wraps. The working example is [here](http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%203.2.0/WorkingExample.html) and it's source can be found [here](http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%203.2.0/Hyphenator.js).

Comment: There's no way to do this, AFAIK. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to alternate the line colours or something?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think there is a way (calculating text width by adding the width of each letter) but it's really dirty. If you could write the same as an answer I would accept it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is like to Search For and Highlight Text. 

using javascript you can learn it here:

[Search For and Highlight Text](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm)

or here:

[how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word)

just download/save the web page there and you can learn it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got me well - yes, your example shows how to add tags at the beginning and the end of a word/phrase. But my problem is not the part of adding the tags but determining where to add them - I would like to put `<span>` on the beginning of each line of the text and '</span>' on the end of it.

Comment: But it's still an answer for another problem - I still don't know WHERE to add the tags in the text. I knew HOW to do it from the very beggining. I want to know where the text overflows the div in which it is put where is it wrapped, moved to a new line.