# Highlight text in specific position with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight text in a specific position. Something like this: [highlight with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery), but it only highlights the word in the position **n**.

For instance, highlight only the **second** hello in the text "hello, hello, hello"

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, but it's not some concise and clever jQuery - mostly straight up javascript.

```
<div id="content">hello, hello, hello</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var searchKey = "hello"; // text to search for in element
        var elementToSearch = $("#content");  // jquery element with text to search for matches
        var instanceToHighlight = 2; // 1-based;  e.g. 3 = third instance found
        highlightText(searchKey, elementToSearch, instanceToHighlight);
    });

    function highlightText(searchKey, elementToSearch, instanceToHighlight) {
        var content = elementToSearch.html();
        var highlightIndex = instanceToHighlight - 1;
        var lastIndex = -1;
        var i = 0;
        // get the index in the overall text of the instance to highlight
        while (i <= highlightIndex) {
            lastIndex = content.indexOf(searchKey, lastIndex + 1);
            i++;
        }
        var testValue = content.slice(lastIndex, lastIndex + searchKey.length);
        if (testValue !== searchKey) {
            return;  // didn't find an actual match
        }
        // chop up the content string so that the <span> tag can be wedged in around the text to highlight
        var contentBeforeHighlightText = content.substr(0, lastIndex);
        var contentAfterHighlightText = content.substr(lastIndex + searchKey.length, content.length - 1);
        highlightedText = "<span class=\"highlight\">" + searchKey + "</span>";
        content = contentBeforeHighlightText + highlightedText + contentAfterHighlightText;
        elementToSearch.html(content);
    }
</script>
```