# How to select a part of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to select a part of string?

My code (or [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nMzTw/1/)):

```
<div>some text</div>

$(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).html().replace(/text/, '<span style="color: none">$1<\/span>'));
    });
});
```

I tried this method, but in this case is selected all context too:

```
$(function(){
    $('div:contains("text")').css('color','red');
});
```

I try to get like this:

```
<div><span style="color: red">text</span></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight a word with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function () {
    $(this).html(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace(/foo/g, '<span style="color: red">$&<\/span>');
    });
});
```

Comment: What if an atttribute value contains the string "foo"?

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to do? What you're doing at the moment is taking the HTML of each matching DIV, wrapping a span around the word "text" if it appears (literally the word "text") and then setting that as the *text* of the element (and so you'll see the HTML markup on the page).

If you really want to do something with the actual word "text", you probably meant to use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) rather than [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in your first function call:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/text/, '<span style="color: none">$1<\/span>'));
         // ^-- here
}
```

**But** if you're trying to wrap a span around the text of the div, you can use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to do that:

```
$('div').wrap('<span style="color: none"/>');
```

Like this: http://jsbin.com/ucopo3 (in that example, I've used "color: blue" rather than "color: none", but you get the idea).

Comment: Crowder, you got a silver badge in jQuery but you are still not using the callback function as an argument for html() and similar methods?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: :-) That first snippet was meant to be a minimum-changes one to point out where the function change was. My primary point was the `wrap` thing anyway, but apparently he wanted the `replace` for something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('div:contains("text")').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(text)/g, '<span style="color:red;">\$1</span>'));
    });
});
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMzTw/15/

Answer (score 0):

The general practice of interacting with the DOM as strings of HTML using `innerHTML` has many serious drawbacks:

- Event handlers are removed or replaced
- Opens the possibility of script inject attacks
- Doesn't work in XHTML

It also encourages lazy thinking. In this particular instance, you're matching against the string "text" within the HTML with the assumption that any occurrence of the string must be within a text node. This is patently not a valid assumption: the string could appear in a `title` or `alt` attribute, for example.

Use DOM methods instead. This will get round all the problems. The following will use only DOM methods to surround every match for `regex` in every text node that is a descendant of a `<div>` element:

```
$(function() {
    var regex = /text/;

    function getTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            return [node];
        } else {
            var textNodes = [];
            for (var n = node.firstChild; n; n = n.nextSibling) {
                textNodes = textNodes.concat(getTextNodes(n));
            }
            return textNodes;
        }
    }

    $('div').each(function() {
        $.each(getTextNodes(this), function() {
            var textNode = this, parent = this.parentNode;
            var result, span, matchedTextNode, matchLength;
            while ( textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data)) ) {
                matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
                matchLength = result[0].length;
                textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
                    matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
                span = document.createElement("span");
                span.style.color = "red";
                span.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
                parent.insertBefore(span, textNode);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan: I should have been clearer. It won't work with XHTML served as "application/xhtml+xml" (which is the only way a page gets parsed as XML anyway).