# jQuery Highlight Words Except Value of href

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/2676556#2676556) works almost perfectly for my needs.  The problem is that it will also match URL values in the href attribute of an a tag.  So If I have:

```
<a href="/a-link-to-a-porsche-page">This is a link to a porsche page</a>
```

and use this selector:

```
$("a").highlight("porsche", "highlighted");
```

porsche gets matched in both the url and the link text.  What can be done so that values of the href attribute are omitted?

Previously referenced answer for posterity:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
    });
};
```

Didn't know about jsfiddle.  Here's a more complete example based on justkt's response: http://jsfiddle.net/Dzejms/L5Knh/1/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution.  Everything seems to work as expected.  See my jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/k6VYC/1/

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem when `a` is the selector.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DRvqs/).  I can understand if the link tag is wrapped in a div which is the selector, etc, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DRvqs/1/)

Comment: updated question with jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Dzejms/L5Knh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to drill down to the children of each object to make sure that you aren't grabbing the DOM nodes in your innerHTML.

Here is a fairly inefficient example that uses recursion on the children of each matched object:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

    return this.each(function () {
        checkHighlight(this);
    });

    function checkHighlight(obj) {
        var children = $(obj).children();
        if(children.length == 0) {
            doHighlight(obj);
        } else {
            children.each(function() {
                checkHighlight(this);
            });
        }
    }

    function doHighlight(obj) {
        obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
    }
};
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9spT3/).

Comment: Close.  Here's a more real world example of what I'm dealing with: http://jsfiddle.net/Dzejms/L5Knh/1/

Comment: @Dzejms - My earlier version [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Knh/2/).  The only thing it isn't doing is highlighting the alt attribute shown where the broken image is.

Comment: i do like this better than mine, since it works in all situations.  there has to be a way to do this more efficiently though.

Answer (score 5):

------edit------

a cursory search on google turned up [this neat jquery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html).  the idea is the same as what is the other answer, but it uses recursion and regex to make it more efficient.  check it out.

Comment: @justkt, true enough.  i suppose it depends on the use case.

Comment: Try taking a look at `textContent` (Firefox + most browsers) and `innerText` (IE + a few browsers). They differ in terms of whitespace, but you should still be able to search them once you strip out things like newlines.