# RegExp wildcard shouldn't overwrite

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, wildcard

I've found an useful post here on StackOverflow, I use to **hightlight** specific text on a website: [Link to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery#120161)

I'll post it again (modified):

```
function hiliter(word) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
    var repl = '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>';
content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
}
```

Now I tried to use this to **find** something **between `<` and `>`**

```
hiliter('&lt;(.*)&gt;');
```

This finds the correct section I want to hightlight, but **output changes from** e.g. **`<Example>` to `<(.*)>`** on the page.

How do I search with this wildcard, but keep the html from the wildcard search when replacing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to [`.replace` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
function hiliter(word) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, function(match, word) {
         return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';
    });
}
```

`word` will contain the contents of the first capture group, namely what was matched by `.*`, `match` will contains the whole match, i.e. the word including `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

A general note: If you use `innerHTML`, you will destroy and create all the HTML elements. Event handlers bound via JavaScript will be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: @ridgerunner: There is a capture group: `&lt;(.*)&gt;`. I added `word` to provide an example how to access the capture group contents.

Comment: @Felix Kling - right you are. I need to read the question a bit closer next time!

Comment: @ridgerunner: No problem :) Though you have been right too, using a string with the replacement patterns should work as well.