# How do I do this in jQuery? (Match a particular word and make it a color)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have several html paragraph of text, i want to go through every paragraph within .content, and if it contains the word "Hello" or "hello" (or any variation of case), i want to make ONLY that word blue. And the same for "Goodbye" except make it red.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/highlighting-text-with-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a jQuery plugin called highlight for that.

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

```
$('li').highlight('bla');
```

A slight modified version to work with different styles.
http://jsfiddle.net/ReNvf/

Comment: This seems to only allow one highlight class. I need red and blue

Answer (score 1):

I have a plugin that makes this easy, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFDqe/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").highlightText("hello","hello",true);
    $("#content").highlightText("goodbye","goodbye",true);
});​
```

https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-highlightText

**Update**
Since there's literally no documentation on this plugin, I figured i should post some.

```
$(selector).highlightText(string, class, onlyfullmatches)
```

`string` can be any string or regular expression. If it is a string, it will be not be case-sensitive, meaning hello will match HeLlO. If it is a regexp, it will be used as-is.

`class` can be a single class, or a space delimited list of classes.

`onlyfullmatches` should be a boolean value, defaulted to false. If true, the plugin will only match full matches, not partial matches. For example, if it is false, `hello` will match the string `hellow`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each p tag, check for text, assign css:

jsFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/fM7MP/26/ )

```
$('p').each( function(index)
{
    replaceWithColors( $(this) , "hello" , "blue" );
    replaceWithColors( $(this) , "goodbye" , "red" );
});

function replaceWithColors( object , word , color )
{
    var index = $(object).html().toLowerCase().indexOf( word );  

    if ( index > -1 )
    {
        var before = $(object).html().substring( 0 , index );
        var theWord = $(object).html().substring( index , index + word.length );
        var after = $(object).html().substring( index + word.length );

        $(object).html( before + "<span style='color:" + color + "'>" + theWord + "</span>" + after);
    }
}
```

​

Comment: That seems to highlight the entire paragraph red (the paragraph will have many words in it. I only want to create that single word a certain color). Or rather, i could just assign wrap it with a span that has a class and that would probably be good too because then i will just style in CSS

Comment: @Tallboy cleaned it up and made a method you can use for more words.

Answer (score 0):

For highlighting the whole line:

```
$("div:contains('hello')").css("color", "blue");
```

**EDIT:** Since the question was changed to highlighting the word only, you can find the answer for example here:
[Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)
or simply use plugins mentioned by others.

**EDIT:**
Or simply like that:

```
​$("div"​)​.each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/(hello)/g, "<span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/(goodbye)/g, "<span style='color: blue'>$1</span>");
})​;​
```

To ignore but to preserve case use `/(hello)/ig` regular expressions.

Comment: It would be better to add a class, so that styles could be reused.

Comment: This makes the entire selection blue. I'd like to make only that word blue and leave rest of paragraph alone

Comment: OK. Then you can simply use `replace` or plugins mentioned by other guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the need for a plugin:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var blue = /hello/i.exec(txt);
        var red = /goodby/i.exec(txt);
        if (blue) {
            $(this).html(txt.replace(/hello/i, '<span class="blue">' + blue + '</span>'));
        } else if (red) {
            $(this).html(txt.replace(/goodbye/i, '<span class="red">' + red + '</span>'));
        }
    }
});
```

SEE http://jsfiddle.net/99mg7/1/

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().replace(/L/gi, function(str) {
        var cls;
        if (str == str.toLowerCase()) {
            cls = 'blue';
        } else if (str == str.toUpperCase()) {              
            cls = 'red'; 
        }            
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + str + '</span>';
    });

    $(this).html(html);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eJjsu/2/)