# Changing the colour of a specific word throughout an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table with the word "yes" being used in various cells throughout the table. I want to change the color of "yes" to green throughout the table. Now I could obviously put all the "yes" words in a span tag and give it a class, applying a style to the class, but I'd have to go and put a span tag around every single yes word...surely there must be a way of saving space and effort in doing this?

Comment: Is "yes" the only word? i.e. `<td>yes</td>`? That could be done using JavaScript DOM traversal + CSS.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Comment: If yes is the only thing in a container, then just apply the style to the container. If it's part of a longer string then your ONLY option is to wrap it in a span, which becomes the new container.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, I guess the easiest would be to just wrap all the yes text in a span tag and apply the class to it

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer that works best for you (not necessarily mine ;-).

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has the wonderful :contains selector:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("td:contains('yes')").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: Will color every text in `td`

Comment: And it should be green not red. ;-)

Comment: worked with `$("td:contains('yes')").css("color", "blueviolet");` after `</table>`. before `<table>`, it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to accomplish this is to wrap each word in a span, and apply a style to it to make the color green.  You can quickly find all of the "yes" words in your page with a regex like this:

```
 /(?<!-)(\byes\b)(?!([^<]+)?>)(?!-)/ig
```

This will find all the "yes" words outside of html tags.  So the final code would be something like this:

```
$('td').each(function(){
   $(this).html(
        $(this).html()
       .replace(
              /(?<!-)(\byes\b)(?!([^<]+)?>)(?!-)/ig, 
             '<span style="color:green;">$1</span>'
        )
    );
});
```

Explanation of the regex:

The middle part, `(\byes\b)`, matches whole words that are "yes" as a sub-expression. The first bit of the regex, `(?<!-)` is called a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and the last bit of the regex, `(?!([^<]+)?>)(?!-)` is called a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Basically it says find me all the whole words "yes" that aren't followed some non `'<'` characters and a `'>'`, and are not followed or preceeded by a hyphen.  These lookarounds prevents the regex from matching any "yes"'s that appear within a tag or its attributes, and that appear in hyphenated words.  The i and g are flags that say make the search case insensitive (so it matches "Yes" and "yes"), and make the search global (match all instances in a string).  In the replace string, `$1` is a backreference, that says insert the first matched sub-expression here, which in this case is the word "yes" as it appears in the matched string.

Comment: and if your HTML happens to contain a tag with "yes" in its attributes?

Comment: Try it, this regex will ignore those.

Comment: Can you explain the regex ? It would be very helpful to a beginner like me. And what does `$1` do ? Works fine for `yesterday` but not with `yes-terday`

Comment: It shouldn't match yesterday or yes-terday.  Try it out on rubular.com and see if you are getting that issue.  I've added an explanation to my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it does fail for yes-terday.  The \b will match hyphens.

Comment: Right, so I added a lookbehind and lookahead to prevent matches within hyphenated words.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a wonderful explanation. +1. Any suggestion for an easy regex reference ?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great reference.  It has all the usual reference tables, plus tutorials and real world examples.  I use http://www.rubular.com alot as well to test out my regular expressions prior to coding them, since it gives me realtime feedback as I type.

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing in JS

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
{
    var s = tables[i].innerHTML;
    s = s.replace('yes', '<span style="color:green">yes</span>');
    tables[i].innerHTML = s;
}
```

Comment: I think you would still need to put `s` back into the innerHTML for this to work. something like `tables[i].innerHTML = tables[i].innerHTML.replace('yes', '<span style="color:red">yes</span>');`

Comment: @Tyrsius Thank you, I was thinking of it as a pointer to the inner html i guess :D

Comment: This will also replace yes if it appears within a tag, for example in a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you can use something like:

```
$('#tableID')
  .find('td')
    .each(function () {
      if ($(this).html() == 'yes') {
        $(this).addClass('MyClass');
      }
    });
```

will only work if 'yes' or whatever you put in the string is the entire html content of that `<td>`