# In html or css how can I set a specific word to always be a certain colour?

Tags: html, css

I'm using html & css.
I want a certain word to always be set to the colour red.
I can use the span tags to set one word to red, but I don't want to have to type this out for every occurance of the word, is there kind of like a "global" way of doing this?

Thanks.

Lets say the word is "cat" btw.

Comment: just add className and set properties.

Comment: CSS can't match the content of an element.

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can't. CSS styles elements, not arbitrary bits of text.

You could programatically modify the document (either server side or with client side JS) to add additional markup (e.g. `<span class="cat">` and `</span>`) around the words you care about (being careful to only alter words in regular text nodes and not in CDATA sections or attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this either manually or with Javascript using regular expressions. A good jQuery plugin is http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html