# Highlight similar text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have large text containers and i want to compare and highlight them using jquery. The question answered here [highlight a word with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery) is perfect except it contains repetition of text. Here is an example

```
<div id="source">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</div>
<div id="similar1">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div id="similar2">consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
```

Now I want to match similar1 and similar2 with source div. The solution in above link suggests following code:

```
 $("#similar1").highlight("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
 $("#similar2").highlight("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
```

As you can see I have to repeat source text everytime. Is it possible to get contents directly from source div? i.e.

```
 $("#similar1").highlight($('#source').val());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes and text():

```
<div id="similar1" class="similar">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div id="similar2" class="similar">consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>


$(".similar").highlight($('#source').text());
```

Answer (score 4):

`.val()` should be used only on input fields such as text field, drop downs, e.t.c.

You should use `.text()` or `.html()` to get the content of elements like `div/span/e.t.c`

Try below,

```
$("#similar1").highlight($('#source').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple elements at once.

`$("#similar1, #similar2").highlight("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");`

You can also use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text contents of your div.

`$("#similar1, #similar2").highlight($("#source").text());`