# How to bold specific Strings in an h:column

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF data table that is displaying data based off a search successfully.  However, I'm not sure how to selectively bold certain text data in a particular column.

So, for instance, I would like this text...

> Here is some text that would be inside the h:column

to show up like this on the page...

> Here is some **text** that would be inside the h:column

Here's what my data table looks like

Results:

```
<h:dataTable var="results"
             value="#{logSearcherBean.results}"
             border="1">
    <h:column>#{results.logName}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{results.matchLine}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: What are the preconditions? Why exactly should exactly the part "text" be bold?

Comment: "text" represents text that is being searched for in several pages.  When matches are found, I would like the "text" to be highlighted in the search results

Comment: @BalusC - I've read that I could use `escape="false"` and then put in html but the results may already have html in them from what I've seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *either* homebrew an [EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) which manipulates the column value and returns the desired HTML,

```
<h:outputText value="#{my:highlight(results.logName, logSearcherBean.query)}" escape="false" />
```

*(note that this is due to `escape="false"`, which is mandatory to present HTML literally, also sensitive to XSS attacks if the `logName` is a value which is fully controlled by the enduser)*

*Or* grab JavaScript/jQuery which manipulates the returned HTML, see also this related question: [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Hi all,

```
                    <p:column id="lastName"
                              headerText="Last Name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{person.lastName}" style="#{myBean.getStyle(person.lastName)}"/>
                    </p:column>
```

And in the bean:

```
public String getStyle(String str) {
    return str.equals(keyword) ? "background-color: yellow" : "";
}
```

All best and happy coding!