# span tag not adding in pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote this code to replace a word in pre tag with a text in span tag(same word) but its only adding its as text not the dom part that is the span is not adding up only span's content is

```
line=$('pre.line[id="'+line_id+'"]');
text=$(line).html();
word_id=text.indexOf(word);
alert(text);

strf=text.substr(0,word_id);
strb=text.substr(word_id+word.length,text.length)


$(line).empty().append(strf);
$(line).append('<span name="blue" style="color:white">'+word+'</span>');
$(line).append(strb);
```

Comment: Post a functional example that illustrates your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ugtFx/

Comment: you can see the actual aim is to get the word in different color and thats why i need it in <span> and its not happening

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight a word with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

Comment: First of all, you haven't selected to include jQuery in your fiddle...

Comment: I wrote some text manipulation functions for fun if you want to have a look http://jsfiddle.net/scarsick/tX4Ge/1/

Comment: that answers is for a plugin and that plugin predefined tag to highlight them  . i am adding these tag dynamically and in the inspect element i dont see the dom (span) added only the text in the span is adding

Comment: heyyyyy ghost i just included the jquery lib in jsfiddle and it worked there !! why is it not working at my end :/