# How to highlight all matching strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

A page contains a search input field and a table.

How to highlight, in the table, all substrings that match the text in the input field?

I have tried this, but it changes the background of the td element.

```
$(".projects-list > tbody > tr > td:contains('"+$(this).val()+"')").css("background", "#6a5acd");
```

How to highlight only the part of text that match?

Comment: can you paste you html too ?

Comment: You should wrap the matching texts with an element. You can't set style to the textNodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight a word with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

Comment: the matching text is currently not wrap with an element but of course we need to dynamically add an element. What's the best way to do it ?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WtF9J/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split(matchingText).join(wrappedMatchingText)` on each of the target cells.

```
$('.projects-list td').each(function (i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    $e.html($e.html().split(text).join('<span class="matching">' + text + '</span>'));
});
```

This would wrap all instances of the target string(stored in the variable `text`) inside individual `span.matching` tags

<del>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/L6M5p/)</del> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/L6M5p/4/)

Comment: Just investigate the DOM to see the sea of nested `.matching` elements.

Comment: @BlackSheep On clicking the 'highlight' button multiple times, you mean? Fixed, I think. See the updated fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Yes, the updated fiddle doesn't create nested elements, just a note, Firefox doesn't support the non-standard `innerText` property. It supports `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is html,

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell 1</td>
<td>cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2</td>
<td>row 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("td:contains('cell 1')").css("color","#6a5acd");//color highlighting 

})
```

And reference link,

http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/fe485/

Comment: I think what OP means that if you type `cell` it should highlight `cell` only and not complete content of the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}
```

then

```
$(".projects-list > tbody > tr > td .highlighted").contents().unwrap();
var search = RegExp.escape(this.value);
$(".projects-list > tbody > tr > td").html(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp('(' + search + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WtF9J/)

Note: If the cells has html contents that is not handled here

Comment: Why does this break down if I press backspace, when there is just one character in the `input` tag, and try to type something?