# Javascript get the text visible on the display

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page which is structured in two parts (div), a header and a container part in which some text is displayed.
The text in the container part is large, and it is scrollable.
I need to get the exact same text displayed on the window and to perform some actions on the displayed text, such as highlight an element.
I have found something about getting the scroll position, but what I need is the actual content starting at that position.
It is possible to obtain that?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you provide an example jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far :)

Comment: It is not duplicate, becaus I want the text at some position, ant there he wants the position of some text.

Comment: I don't have a code on how to get the text, because I did not find anything. I  have mentioned that I found ho to get the position (x, y) but not the content.

Comment: I have found what I need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery