# Add span class a specific word with regexp

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

```
<div id="mytext">
"Albert" Einstein German: 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955 was a German-born theoretical physicist.
He developed the general theory of "relativity", one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics). 
He is best known in popular culture for "his" mass–energy equivalence formula "E = mc2" (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation").
</div>
```

i want in " " words add span class with javascript regexp

```
<div id="mytext">
<span class="myclass">"Albert"</span> Einstein German: 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955 was a German-born theoretical physicist.
He developed the general theory of <span class="myclass">"relativity"</span>, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics). 
He is best known in popular culture for <span class="myclass">"his"</span> mass–energy equivalence formula <span class="myclass">"E = mc2"</span (which has been dubbed the world's most famous equation).
</div>
```

Comment: explain more with detail ... nobody get what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a plain vanilla JS way and a jQuery way:

jQuery

```
$("#mytext").html( $("#mytext").text().replace(/("[^"]*")/g,"<span>$1</span>") )
```

JavaScript

```
var text = document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = text.replace(/("[^"]*")/g,"<span>$1</span>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Was answered a few times.

http://jsfiddle.net/59Nrk/

Exmaple:

```
$.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b"+str+"\\b", "gi");

    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + matched + "</span>";});
    });
};

// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    var $txtBlock = $('#mytext'),
        highlightClass = 'myclass';
    $txtBlock.highlight('Einstein', highlightClass);
    $txtBlock.highlight('relativity', highlightClass);
    $txtBlock.highlight('his', highlightClass);

});
```

[Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)