# How can I color specific letters in html element text?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some `span` with some words in it, like

```
        <span id="phrase">Here are some words</span>
```

I need to color all the `'e'` characters red.

I think of taking the `span.innerText property`, remove text node from span element and add some more spans inside (or instead), and give them necessary style.

Is it the only way, or it could be solved in a more elegant way?

Comment: Can be dine using [this (jQuery Highlight)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery).

Comment: I added a little code, just in case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can surely do it with javascript:

```js
var span = document.getElementById('phrase'),
    text = span.innerHTML.split('').map(function(el) {
        return '<span class="char-' + el.toLowerCase() + '">' + el + '</span>';
    }).join('');
  
span.innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.char-e {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="phrase">Here are some words</span>
```

For convenience it wraps each character with a span with corresponding class name, which makes it easy to assign individual styles.

**Warning:** However I would not recommend doing this with large texts because the code above replaces `innerHTML` it can break your HTML if it contains other nested elements. But for small titles with only text this is not going to be a problem.

If you want to work with more complex HTML markup (with children elements) the function needs to be improved to work recursively on child items text content.

Comment: That would break if the span includes a link, or other child nodes.

Comment: @MildlySerious but the OP didn't talk about link's..

Comment: @MildlySerious Yes, it's true. That's why I mentioned that it is only applicable for small texts like titles, etc.

Comment: @MildlySerious but `innerText` is MS only, it won't work in FF.

Comment: @Superdrac I just mentioned it. Someone not think of that in case it breaks.

Comment: @Dmitry Even then, you couldn't put it back because it would overwrite the nodes. You would have to iterate over the child nodes recursively if you wanted a fully working solution. At that point you could also use blast.js though.

Comment: @MildlySerious, yes just saw it.. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

More complex implementation (which contain dfsq code) which keep tags:

```js
function addColor(domNode, color, letter){
 if(domNode.nodeType!=1||!domNode.hasAttribute('edited')){
  if(domNode.nodeType==3){
   var newText=document.createElement('span');    
   newText.innerHTML=domNode.textContent;
   newText.setAttribute('edited', true);
   var text = newText.innerHTML.split('').map(function(el){
     if(el==letter){
    return '<i style=\"color:'+color+'\">'+el+'</i>';
     }
     else{
    return el;
     }
    }).join('');
    newText.innerHTML=text;
    domNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newText,domNode);
  }
  for(var i=0; i<domNode.childNodes.length;i++){
   addColor(domNode.childNodes[i], color, letter);
  }
 }
} 

addColor(document.getElementById('phrase'), 'red', 'e');
```

```html
<span id="phrase">Here are <a href="#"> test</a>  some text <p> some text again </p> some woreds</span>
```

With a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e6c3yy0j/

Comment: I improved it if you wanna change **more than one** type of character. [http://jsfiddle.net/e6c3yy0j/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/e6c3yy0j/10/)

( note: Attempt 7 and below are not mine, but I laughed so hard at them :D )

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not so ugly to use javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
   var text = $("#phrase").html().replace(/e/g, '<span class="red">e</span>');
    $("#phrase").html(text)
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vzxebauw/)

Comment: Did you saw jQuery in the tags ?

Comment: Breaks as soon as there is something else than text. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzxebauw/1/) That should at least be mentioned.

Comment: @Superdrac jQuery is javascript, so please don't be ironic ... it's just the fastest way I found to show it. I could have demonstrated it with dart, angular or whatever, it still javascript ...

MildySerious Do you need this example fixed with html inside or it's just to promote your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Split each character in the string and if the character is `'e'`, then give the red color using `fontcolor` function.

### Code

```
var s1 = document.getElementById("phrase");
var str = s1.innerHTML;
var newText = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if (str[i] == 'e') {
     newText+= str.charAt(i).fontcolor("red");
     }
     else {
        newText += str[i];
    }
}
s1.innerHTML = newText;
```

### [Find Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8tkbqcjo/)

Comment: `String.prototype.fontcolor` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't target specific letters in a text (except for the first one using `:first-letter`). So yes, your only option is to wrap them with an element. A `span` would work, the guys from FontAwesome like to use `i` instead.

So, for example, you could do this:

```
<span id="phrase">H<i>e</i>r<i>e</i> are som<i>e</i> words</span>
```

And add this to your CSS:

```
.phrase i {
    font-style: normal; /* Because I is italic by default */
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: best solution .. simple and elegant

Answer (score -1):

If this you only need 1 known string to be red then you don't need javascript:

html

```
<span id="phrase">H<span class="my-class">e</span>r<span class="my-class">e</span> ar<span class="my-class">e</span> som<span class="my-class">e</span> words</span>
```

css:

```
.my-class {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: Notice the Javascript  tag. I'm guessing OP doesn't want to manually add classes to every e

Comment: true, but putting it out there - javascript is not needed if the string is known. lets see what OP says.

Comment: Of course, i need all that stuff to work dynamically. The thing is contents of the span are changing dynamically and so I need to apply transformation with javascript each time.