# How can i change the specific character color in the textarea using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a line of text in the textarea is like below

```
<textarea>This is a line of text for test.</textarea>
```

Now I would like to change the word color of some character is like below.
[image]

I don't want to change HTML textarea tag to display this text. I would like to implement is using jQuery. How can i do that?

Comment: do you know which alphabets you want to change the color of? are you sure the html will never change?

Comment: This may be help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485729/how-can-i-color-specific-letters-in-html-element-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. but jQuery code runs only once

```js
var alpha = ["s","x","e","T"];
var res = "", cls = "";
var t = $("#txt").text();

for (i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<alpha.length; j++) {
        if (t[i] == alpha[j]) {cls = "red";}
    }
    res += "<span class='"+cls+"'>"+t[i]+"</span>";
    cls="";
}
$("#result").html(res);
```

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}
#result {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt">This is a line of text for test.</textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

It's  possible to separate coloring of text if you use `contenteditable` element.

Here is fiddle of coloring particular chars on the fly:

http://www.codeply.com/go/YHx9yphpHW

Comment: I would like to see the result in a same textarea. I don't like to see the result in another result div. Is it possible?

Comment: I've appended an answer. look at link

Answer (score 0):

You can't change colors, but what you can do is select a particular character (highlight by way of JavaScript.)

See [Highlighting a piece of string in a TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549250/highlighting-a-piece-of-string-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea>This is a line of text for test.</textarea>

<script>
var counter = 0;
var newTextArea = new Array();
var currentText = $("textarea:first").val();

do{
    var currentLetter = currentText.charAt(counter);
    if(!(counter % 4)){
        $(currentLetter).css('color', 'red');
    }
    newTextArea.push(currentLetter);
    counter++;
}while(counter < currentText.length);

$("textarea:first").val(newTextArea.toString());
</script>
```