# Displaying text inside an HTML input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to display dynamic texts contents inside an HTML input element, some thing similar to how chrome browsers CTRL + F works.

> Like it shows the number of **hits** in the page.

Can anyone please help, if possible how or share some useful materials to achieve the same?

[image]

Comment: Please show your code! What you've tried!

Comment: yes you can do it, using css, jquery.

Comment: `Is it possible to display dynamic texts inside an HTML input element,` You mean highlight the matching content in an input value?

Comment: @gurvinder372 ... no I have edited the question, please see.

Comment: If I got your question right, do you mean HTML text highlight? like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Comment: @lastboy... no its not about highlighting... I have a table in which I i am implementing "Find" not search, and I have implemented the find and highlighting part already using html input element and JS. But, I wanted to know is it possible show the number of matched rows in the table inside the same search box(or the input element) along side the typed keywords which user would enter.

Comment: Everything is possible in HTML/Javascript env. But to help you we need to see how did you implemented it (use jsfiddle)  Since it's really depends what kind of library/framework have you used jquery | angular | native javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using a combination of `relative` and `absolute` positioning on the parent and child elements like this:

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.field__input {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.field__helper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 4px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* this is just fluff to make it look nicer */
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" value="find" class="field__input">
  <span class="field__helper">1 of 5</span>
</div>
```

We use a relatively positioned parent (`.fieldRow`) to wrap around the `input` field. Then, we use a `span` (`.helper`) containing the text we want to display and using `position: absolute;` we can position it to the right of the `input` field. Last of all, we need a little padding on the right hand side of the `input` to stop the inputted value from bleeding into our helper text.