# JS: How to find all matches of words in iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, pdf.js

I have array of words:

```js
['apple', 'mango', 'orange']
```

And i have an `iFrame` on my page (*in the same domain*) and i need to highlight all matches of these words in it. Moreover i need to *change style of these words* (change some text styles and handle click event on them)

Is any solutions for this? Search in PDF js working perfect https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

how i can implement the same ?

Comment: Can you pass these values to iFrame and is the code of page inside iFrame accessible to you?

Comment: is the iframed page under the same domain?

Comment: @KeepMove Yes. Its been stated in question.

Comment: @Rajesh yes, the code into iframe is accessible for me. I can paste some script into inner page.

Comment: Then you should look for searching the document and highlight the words. You can check following link for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery