# how to highlight words or alphbets as user inputs in search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hi i am developing ajax search result.I want to highlight the words and alphabets which user inputs.I use jason api for result.I use regexp but it does not work.
Code is:

```
 var string = data;//search result
 var string2 = keyword;//user input
 var regex = new RegExp( string2, 'g' );
 var pattern=string.match(regex);
```

for example If user type s in input box then all S should be bold in search result.**S**pain,**S**weden like this or much alphabets and words as user inputs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

Comment: refer this link https://jsfiddle.net/tovic/rhYfm/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out https://github.com/ddsky/unibox ? Seems to do what you're asking for. Im not the author though.