# how to just bold partial text instead of whole in td by jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<td> ABCDE </td>
```

```js
$("td:contains('CD')").css("font-weight","Bold");
```

This will bold whole text like: **ABCDE**. How can I just bold text `CD` like "AB**CD**E"?

Comment: You can only set styling on a whole text node. If you want to style part of it you need to split it in to separate nodes, by wrapping the part you want to make bold in a `span`, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a text replacement using HTML markup, but you need to specify the text to replace :

```
$("td:contains('CD')").each(function(td,item){
    $(item).html($(item).html().replace("CD","<b>CD</b>"))
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/qo5zxx9a/

Another solution is to write the cell content using HTML markup:

```
<td>AB<span class="bold">CD</span>E</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/120161/3147508).

```js
function highlight(word, element) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g')
    var repl = '<span class="bold">' + word + '</span>'
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl)
}

var element = document.querySelector('td')
highlight('CD', element)
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td> ABCDE </td>
</table>
```