# How to highlight search results in a multi-layer accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new into JS and I would like to be able to highlight search results in the accordion. For now the code works well for searching

I have tried to use RegExp but I didn't succeed.

```js
(function() {
  var searchTerm, panelContainerId;

  // Create a new contains that is case insensitive
  jQuery.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function(n, i, m) {
    return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };

  jQuery('#accordion_search_bar').on('change keyup paste click', function() {
    searchTerm = jQuery(this).val();

    if (searchTerm.length >= 3) {
      jQuery('#accordion > .panel').each(function() {
        panelContainerId = '#' + jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery(panelContainerId + ':not(:containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + '))').hide();
        jQuery(panelContainerId + ':containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + ')').show().find(".panel-collapse").collapse("show");
      });
    } else {
      jQuery(".panel-group > div").show();
      jQuery(".panel-group > div").find(".panel-collapse").collapse("hide");
    }
  });
}());
```

Comment: i thought your picture was tom from myspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it without changing the markup.

If you're ok with that though you can replace the searched for text with a coloured `<span>` element. Give it a class so you can remove it when needed too.

Colouring it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041257/3739842)

I'd amend it so you can remove the span when you want to refresh the search by adding a class to the span:

```
function color_word(text_id, word, color) {
    words = $('#' + text_id).text().split(' ');
    words = words.map(function(item) { return item == word ? "<span class='highlight' style='color: " + color + "'>" + word + '</span>' : item });
    new_words = words.join(' ');
    $('#' + text_id).html(new_words);
}
```

So to remove it we could do something like:

```
function removeHighlight(container)
{
    let highlight = $(container).find('.highlight').first();

    const markupToReplace = $(highlight).get(0).outerHTML;
    const highlightedText = $(highlight).text();

    $(container).html($(container).html().replace(markupToReplace, highlightedText));
}
```